# Returning empty string when string_agg has no records

Tags: postgresql, null, aggregate, concat

I am trying to return a text field in a PostgreSQL query that is of the form

```
'stringOne' || string_agg(field, ',') || 'stringTwo'
```

where for certain elements in the group clause, `field` is always null. I want, and expect, to end up with `stringOnestringTwo` in that case, but instead I get `NULL`.

Why is this, and how do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

## Example

Suppose I have the tables

```
foo                 bar
+----+--------+     +----+-------+--------------+
| id | name   |     | id | fooid | baz          |
+----+--------+     +----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | FooOne |     |  1 |     1 | FooOneBazOne |
|  2 | FooTwo |     |  2 |     1 | FooTwoBazTwo |
+----+--------+     +----+-------+--------------+
```

and I run the query

```
SELECT
  foo.name AS foo,
  'Bazzes: ' || string_agg(bar.baz, ', ') AS bazzes
FROM
  foo LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.fooid = foo.id
GROUP BY
  foo.name
```

Then I want (and expect) to get the resultset

```
+--------+------------------------------------+
| foo    | bazzes                             |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| FooOne | Bazzes: FooOneBazOne, FooOneBazTwo |
| FooTwo | Bazzes:                            |  <== NOT NULL
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

but instead, the second row is `('FooTwo', NULL)`. How can I modify this query so that the second row returns `('FooTwo', 'Bazzes: ')`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [**`COALESCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to catch and replace `NULL` values:

```
SELECT f.name AS foo
     , 'Bazzes: ' || COALESCE(string_agg(b.baz, ', '), '') AS bazzes
FROM   foo f
LEFT   JOIN bar b ON b.fooid = f.id
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The null-safe [`concat()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is another convenient option as you found yourself, in particular to concatenate *multiple* values. I suggest the variant [**`concat_ws()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) ("**w**ith **s**eparator"), though, to avoid the trailing space.

Nested in a more efficient query (while querying all foos):

```
SELECT f.name AS foo
     , concat_ws(' ', 'Bazzes:', baz_agg) AS bazzes
FROM   foo f
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT fooid AS id
        , string_agg(b.baz, ', ') AS baz_agg
   FROM   bar b
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (id);
```

#### Why `NULL`?

Almost all aggregate functions return `NULL` if all source fields are `NULL` (no non-null values, to be precise) - `count()` being the exception for practical reasons. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

> It should be noted that except for `count`, these functions return a
> null value when no rows are selected. In particular, `sum` of no rows
> returns null, not zero as one might expect, and `array_agg` returns null
> rather than an empty array when there are no input rows. The `coalesce`
> function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for null when necessary.

Related:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943343/939860)
- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I have found to accomplish this is to swap out the string concatenation operator for the string concatenation function `concat()`. For some reason the former apparently coerces the entire result to `NULL` if one operand is null, as opposed to the latter which effectively casts any `NULL` arguments to `''`.

So this query performs as desired:

```
SELECT
  foo.name,
  concat('Bazzes: ', string_agg(bar.baz, ', ')) AS bazzes
FROM
  foo LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.fooid = foo.id
GROUP BY
  foo.name
```

It returns the desired result set:

```
+--------+------------------------------------+
| foo    | bazzes                             |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| FooOne | Bazzes: FooOneBazOne, FooOneBazTwo |
| FooTwo | Bazzes:                            |
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

---

## Another option

A second approach is slightly more involved, but I found it first and it may be relevant in other situations, so I'll document it here as well. A `CASE` statement can be used to count the number of elements before passing them to the aggregation function, and return an empty string instead of `NULL` when the answer is zero.

In the original query, replace

```
string_agg(bar.baz, ', ')
```

with

```
CASE count(bar.baz) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE string_agg(bar.baz, ', ') END
```

and the `string_agg` function will only be called when there is at least one string to aggregate. The empty string will be returned and combined correctly with the rest of the text otherwise, instead of coercing the whole result to `NULL`.